# .htaccess redirect passing variables (query string) but not page name or directory.

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

trying to get a hold of this but can't quite figure it out.

I need to redirect:

```
domainA.com/myPage.php?some=variables&are=here
```

to:

```
domainB.com/otherPage.php?some=variables&are=here
```

it also needs to work if myPage.php is in a directory.. but redirects wihout the directory on domainB

```
domainA.com/folder/myPage.php?some=variables&are=here
```

goes to:

```
domainB.com/otherPage.php?some=variables&are=here
```

This just seems so simple but I can't get my syntax right.

Comment: Sorry I could not help. I rather test it first.

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in the document root of your domainA.com domain, add these (preferably above any other rules)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  domainA.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule /?myPage\.php$ http://domainB.com/otherPage.php [L]
```

Thr query string params will get appended automatically